# Why do pointers to variables in a vector stay valid?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Take this code for example:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector.push_back(a);
myVector.push_back(b);
myVector.push_back(c);
int * b_pointer;
b_pointer = &myVector[1]
```

In my experience `b_pointer` will alway point to `b` even though the vector may reallocate which should make it so `b_pointer` points to junk data. Is there ever a situation in which this wont work?

Comment: `b_pointer` does not point to `b`, it points to the second element stored in `my_vector`.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious if I were to call `myVector.erase(myVector.begin())` would `b_pointer still` be valid?

Comment: `Iterator/pointer/reference invalidation` is what you're looking for. `.push_back()` invalidates pointers, if reallocation happens.

Comment: You are incorrect in your assumption that the pointer "stays valid".  What you really mean is that the pointer seems to work **despite** being invalid.

Comment: Likely the vector's initial capacity is bigger than 3, so likely there's no reallocation. Please note the "likely".

Comment: More likely after the reallocation the old memory is not reused, so *b_pointer will still be 2.

Answer (score 4):

You are essentially asking whether an iterator stays valid (Although, the type of a vector iterator is not necessarily the same as a simple pointer)

The documentation for `std::vector<>::insert` says

> If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references
>   related to the container are invalidated. Otherwise, only those
>   pointing to position and beyond are invalidated, with all iterators,
>   pointers and references to elements before position guaranteed to keep
>   referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

The thing you are probably noticing is that when a realloc happens, it sometimes just extends the current allocation if there is space available.

Comment: Alternately, a realloc happens, copying the whole vector data to a new location.  The old location still happens to have the same *value* as before, but that's not guaranteed to stay that way.

Answer (score 0):

After a reallocation of `myVector`'s internal buffer happens, `b_pointer` will point to invalid memory, plain and simple. Dereferencing it will result in Undefined Behaviour.

However, it's very possible that the memory to which it points still contains the data which it held previously; why would some pay the cost of trashing it somehow? Nobody's legally able to access it anyway. If sufficient allocations happen in the meantime, it will eventually get overridden by something else.